# Launching the app will only display black screen in livecode 5.5.5

Tags: android, livecode

I created an android livecode app which is to display a hello world dialog. When I selected 
**Development->test**
 it will launch the application but only display black screen. Anything I missed?

I am using Livecode 5.5.5 and real device version: Android 4.1.2.

Comment: You are testing in the emulator but report the version number of your real device. Which Android version number do you use for testing in the emulator? What happens if you do a test with a completely empty stack, does it still show the all-black screen? Are you sure the screen is completely black, or do you mean the trial splash screen?

Comment: Hi Mark, I am testing using the real device not emulator. I have device connected and I can select it as test target under Development tab. Actually it is now working using the trial version livecode 5.5.4 but it does not work on livecode 5.5.5 which I have a license. Yes, the screen is totally black in livecode 5.5.5.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to fix my problem. This works on my livecode 5.5.5 now.

Here's what I did:

1. In Livecode 5.5.5, I renamed the folder "Android" to something different such as "Android1". This folder is located under Contents/Tools/Runtime.
2. In livecode 5.5.4, I copy the Android folder located under Contents/Tools/Runtime and paste it inside Livecode 5.5.5/Contents/Tools/Runtime

Hope this helps to others, if they will encounter same problem as this.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that all settings (in preferences window and standalone settings window) in 5.5.5 are the same as in 5.5.4. Test your stack in 5.5.4, then save it and don't change anything when testing in 5.5.5. Does it work?

If this doesn't work, check your RunRev web store account and check if you really don't have a license for 5.5.4. What type of license do you have? PAYG? Perpetual?

If you really don't have a license for 5.5.4, ask RunRev to send you one.

Comment: thank you. Your idea help me fix my problem though is not from the settings.

Answer (score 0):

One possible cause of these symptoms - which has bitten me in the past - is if you're working on a cross-platform project and have iOS extensions in the "Copy Files" tab of the Standalone Settings.

Comment: Thanks Ben but I don't have iOS extensions in the "Copy Files" since this is just a simple hello world app. Just wondering why it doesn't work on livecode 5.5.5 where in it works on Livecode 5.5.4.